# SSIS Data flow component shows data in preview but gives validation error on run

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odbc

I am trying to fetch data from oracle and dump it into SQL server. For this, i am using SSIS package. However, ODBC source component in Data flow does not run when i execute the pakcage. In execution results, it gives me validation error of `VS_ISBROKEN` and `There was an error in getting table schema information. Table has no columns.`

However. when in properties of the component i try to preview the result of my query, it works just fine and does not give error.

Please help!

Comment: Since you are just going from Oracle to SQL Server, instead of applying SSIS, have you considered instead setting up a Linked Server under Server Objects in SQL Server Management Studio?  Then all you need to apply is the OPENQUERY in a SELECT statement to pull over the records from any table shared in the Linked Server setup.  Check out the following link for setting up a Linked Server: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/280106

Comment: The following link also provides examples of using OPENQUERY to pull records from a Linked Server pointing to an Oracle database.  This is much easier than using an SSIS package and conversions are mostly handled automatically.  https://dbamohsin.wordpress.com/2012/09/05/openquery-using-linked-server-sql-to-oracle/